# Databind text to a string property

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I'm new to Silverlight and the concept of data-binding and I still fail on resolving my problem. I haven't manage to find a solution after few days of research.

Here is my problem :

I correctly bind a `String` property to the text of my `TextBlock` as you can see below :

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Grid  Background="Blue"  DataContext="{StaticResource WP8Displayable}">
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbCanvasTitle" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding titleDisplayable}" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>          
</Grid>
```

**WP8Displayable.cs**

```
public class WP8Displayable : IDisplayable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public String title { get; set; }


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members


    public string titleDisplayable
    {
        get
        {
            return title;
        }
        set
        {
            if (title != value)
            {
                title = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("titleDisplayable");
            }
        }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Used to notify the page that a data context property changed
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public void setTitle(String s)
    {
        this.title = s;

        NotifyPropertyChanged("titleDisplayable");
    }
}
```

I have a thread in my `MainPage.xaml.cs` that can instantiate one or more instance of `WP8Displayable` class. When one of the instance call `setTitle(String s)` the text in my TextBlock does not update, it seems that my `DataContext` is not set up properly.

**EDIT :**

My thread is launched in the `MainPage.xaml.cs` in the `MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` method and does something like this :

```
  var instanceWP8Displayable = new WP8Displayable();
  //tbCanvasTitle.DataContext = instanceWP8Displayable;   HERE IS WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO ON XAML
  instanceWP8Displayable.setTitle("my Title");
```

**EDIT 2 : App.xaml**

```
<Application
x:Class="AMS.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:windows="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
xmlns:ioC="clr-namespace:AMS.Controller">

<!--Application Resources-->
<Application.Resources>

    <windows:ResourceDictionary>
        <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AMS" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
        <ioC:Locator x:Key="Locator" x:Name="Locator" />
    </windows:ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid  Background="Blue"  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=WP8Displayable}">
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbCanvasTitle" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding titleDisplayable}" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>          
    </Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:WP8Displayable />
    </Grid.DataContext>
    </Grid>
```

**How can I dynamically set up the DataContext in that case** ? And **Is it possible to link more than one instance to the same object ?**

If anyone as a clue or feels that my question is not clear enough don't hesitate to tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: The title updates when you set the datacontext in the code behind right?

Comment: Yes it works. I tried it to be sure my binding is ok. But I don't know when and how many WP8Displayable instance will be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you check out [MVVMLight](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/) which will help you eliminate a lot of boiler plate code you have to write e.g. `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Further it provides you with an IoC Container (Inversion of Control) that is most commonly used for the task you are trying to perform. You can implement a simple version of one on your own (see bellow).

You can set the DataContext in XAML but you will need a class that provides the Object, so for instance you could write a class like this (I'm assuming you add it directly to the project and not in a subfolder):

```
public class Locator
{
    public WP8Displayable WP8Displayable
    {
        get { return new WP8Displayable(); }
    }
}
```

Next you will have to register the Locator class in the App.xaml so you can reference it from within your view:

```
<Application
    ...
    xmlns:windows="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
    xmlns:ioC="clr-namespace:YOURAPPNAME">

 <!--Application Resources-->

 <Application.Resources>      
     <windows:ResourceDictionary>
         <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AMS" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
         <ioC:Locator x:Key="Locator" x:Name="Locator" />
     </windows:ResourceDictionary>
 </Application.Resources>



        ...

</Application>
```

Now we can set the DataContext in XAML:

```
<Grid  Background="Blue"  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=WP8Displayable}">
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbCanvasTitle" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding titleDisplayable}" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>          
</Grid>
```

HTH

Comment: Unfortunately `ResourceDictionary` is not supported in Silverlight project. So if I understand well I have to create my `WP8Displayable` objects in a Class that can be used for setting up a `DataContext` in  XAML right ?

Comment: @Yann Sorry my bad deleted one line too many, with the additional namespace you can use `ResourceDictionary` in a WP8 project.

Comment: @Yann and yes if you do not use it via code behind. You could of course adjust the method so it will always return the same instance of the class. So yes you can set a `WP8Displayable` instance as `DataContext` of multiple views.

Comment: Thanks to you I discovered the "Inversion of Control" pattern. I'm actually trying to understand it in order to apply it correctly.

Comment: @Yann yeah this goes into that direction. Sorry the Locator method should have been a property or else it can't find it. Further be sure to replace the string YOURAPPNAME with your actual app name.

Comment: I cannot do exactly the same as you because my `ResourceDictionary` needs a key (or it doesn't compile). The `DataContext` in the **MainPage.xaml** does not work because the "resource "Locator" could not be resolve". So I added a key and set the `ResourceDictionary` as the `StaticResource` to suppress the bug but even if it does compile the binding fails again. The title is not updated as the String is.

Comment: I think you are going wrong somewhere within the app.xaml, could you provide the lines concerning the dictionary and the imports? I created the code above within a WP8 demo-project so I know it must work ;)

Comment: I edited my question in order to show you all my App and MainPage xaml. My `Locator` class is inside the folder _Controller_. I will reedit it when the problem will be solve in order to make it easier to read for other people. Thank you a lot for the good help your provide !

Comment: It's compiling with success but the UI title is not changing. I'm lost with this. Unfortunately debugging XAML is a real pain.

Comment: @Yann why don't you open a new question for that and I'll have a look at it (this isn't the same topic as before..)? Try setting the title to some default value in the constructor of the WP8Displayable, then you know that the binding has worked. Another thing is look at the output in VisualStudio when you access the page there you would see if anything with the binding is going wrong..

Comment: You're right! I will create a new question for this. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Your way for declaration property is wrong.
Plz Declare property as below;

```
#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

public string _titleDisplayable;
public string titleDisplayable
{
    get
    {
        return _titleDisplayable;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_titleDisplayable != value)
        {
            _titleDisplayable = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("titleDisplayable");
        }
    }
}
```

and In class methods plz write below code:

```
public void setTitle(string s)
{
    this.titleDisplayable = s;

}
```

Plz changes ur code as per above code.

Thanks ,
Hitesh.

Comment: Thanks for answer but my biding is working correctly. If I create an instance of WP8Displayable and set the `DataContext` like in this line : `tbCanvasTitle.DataContext = instanceWP8Displayable;` (the one in comment in my code) it works fine but the problem is I cannot use that line.